# CMD command not working inside Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

```
FROM timberio/vector:0.35.0-debian
COPY vector-config-docker.toml /etc/vector/
WORKDIR /etc/vector/
RUN echo "printing vector location..."
RUN which vector && echo $(which vector)
RUN echo "printing vector version..."
RUN echo $(vector --version)
RUN echo $(ls -l '/etc/vector/vector-config-docker.toml')
CMD ["vector", "--config", "/etc/vector/vector-config-docker.toml"]
```

Above is my docker file.

Docker build also success with below command

```
docker build -t vector-agent .
```

While doing `docker run -p 8090:8090 vector-agent:latest`

Iam encountering below issue.

```
error: unrecognized subcommand 'vector'

Usage: vector [OPTIONS] [COMMAND]

For more information, try '--help'.
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 2):

The `timberio/vector:0.35.0-debian` image already defines `ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/vector"]`. The value of the CMD is appended to the ENTRYPOINT to define the process that is run when the container is started. So you only need:

```
CMD ["--config", "/etc/vector/vector-config-docker.toml"]
```

For your container to be started with the process:

```bash
/usr/bin/vector --config /etc/vector/vector-config-docker.toml
```

Comment: Thank you. Iam able to resolve it by replacing CMD line by             ENTRYPOINT ["vector", "--config", "/etc/vector/vector-config-docker.toml"]